# How do you authenticate a VueJS app with Azure AD?

Tags: node.js, azure, vue.js, vuejs2, azure-active-directory

I'm setting up an app using the VueJS 2.x framework and it needs to authenticate users via the Azure Active Directory service. I already have "login info" (Auth and Token URLs) neccessary for the service.

So far, I've only encountered [one article](https://auth0.com/authenticate/vuejs/azure-active-directory) that shows the setup in VueJS, but it relies on a third party service (Auth0) - adding uneccessary convolution in the process.

How do you proceed when there [aren't any VueJS npm modules](https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/adal) that allow for doing authenticating easily? Or do you have to rely on a library outside of Vue like [Adal JS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: If you're hosted in Azure App Service you can use EasyAuth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication. That's pretty much Authentication-as-a-Service (i'm not gonna acronym that), since you don't have to write code for it, it happens before the request reaches your app.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To solve this very problem, I leaned on **ADAL JS**. I've made a **Vue + Vue-Router** sample application available [here](https://github.com/matt-ankerson/vue-adal) - but I'll include the important pieces below.

#### In your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "adal-angular": "^1.0.15",
    "vue": "^2.5.2",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
},
```

#### A basic wrapper module for the ADAL JS library:

```
import AuthenticationContext from 'adal-angular/lib/adal.js'

const config = {
  tenant: 'your aad tenant',
  clientId: 'your aad application client id',
  redirectUri: 'base uri for this application',
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
};

export default {
  authenticationContext: null,
  /**
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  initialize() {
    this.authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.authenticationContext.isCallback(window.location.hash) || window.self !== window.top) {
        // redirect to the location specified in the url params.
        this.authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();
      }
      else {
        // try pull the user out of local storage
        let user = this.authenticationContext.getCachedUser();

        if (user) {
          resolve();
        }
        else {
          // no user at all - go sign in.
          this.signIn();
        }
      }
    });
  },
  /**
   * @return {Promise.<String>} A promise that resolves to an ADAL token for resource access
   */
  acquireToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.authenticationContext.acquireToken('<azure active directory resource id>', (error, token) => {
        if (error || !token) {
          return reject(error);
        } else {
          return resolve(token);
        }
      });
    });
  },
  /**
   * Issue an interactive authentication request for the current user and the api resource.
   */
  acquireTokenRedirect() {
    this.authenticationContext.acquireTokenRedirect('<azure active directory resource id>');
  },
  /**
   * @return {Boolean} Indicates if there is a valid, non-expired access token present in localStorage.
   */
  isAuthenticated() {
    // getCachedToken will only return a valid, non-expired token.
    if (this.authenticationContext.getCachedToken(config.clientId)) { return true; }
    return false;
  },
  /**
   * @return An ADAL user profile object.
   */
  getUserProfile() {
    return this.authenticationContext.getCachedUser().profile;
  },
  signIn() {
    this.authenticationContext.login();
  },
  signOut() {
    this.authenticationContext.logOut();
  }
}
```

#### In the app's entry point (main.js if you used vue-cli):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import authentication from './authentication'

// Init adal authentication - then create Vue app.
authentication.initialize().then(_ => {
  /* eslint-disable no-new */
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
  });
});
```

#### For your Vue router configuration:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import authentication from '../authentication'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld,
      meta: {
        requiresAuthentication: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

// Global route guard
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuthentication)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
      // only proceed if authenticated.
      next();
    } else {
      authentication.signIn();
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

#### In your Vue components:

```
import authentication from './authentication'
...
computed: {
  isAuthenticated() {
    return authentication.isAuthenticated();
  }
},
methods: {
  logOut() {
    authentication.signOut();
  }
}
```

#### Add access token to request headers

The below is an example of a vue-resource http interceptor, but any method will do.

```
Vue.http.interceptors.push(function (request, next) {
  auth.acquireToken().then(token => {
    // Set default request headers for every request
    request.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    request.headers.set('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', 'api key');
    request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
    // continue to next interceptor
    next();
  });
});
```

Hopefully this saves somebody a little time :)

Comment: Besides the use of http (instead of the recommended Axios), this gets an upvote. It's pretty close to what we used (albeit somewhat different)

Comment: Am I right in understanding that you are using implicit grant?

Comment: In your second code block you have `<azure active directory resource id>` What is that as there's nothing in Azure with that label?

Comment: Hi Matt, i was able to use your example to authenticate with adal to azure AD, now i need to call a REST api i was looking in the code block below,  what is the 'resource id' meaning? is it the clientID from the AD webApi? acquireToken() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.authenticationContext.acquireToken('resource id', (error, token) => {
      if (error || !token) {
        return reject(error);
      } else {
        return resolve(token);
      }
    });
  });
},

Answer (score 12):

**Disclaimer:** I am the author of this plugin.

Use [vue-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-adal) via npm:

```
npm install vue-adal
```

**Basic Usage**

````
import Adal from 'vue-adal'
Vue.use(Adal, {
// This config gets passed along to Adal, so all settings available to adal can be used here.
  config: {
    // 'common' (multi-tenant gateway) or Azure AD Tenant ID
    tenant: '<guid>',

    // Application ID
    clientId: '<guid>',

    // Host URI
    redirectUri: '<host addr>',

    cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
  },

  // Set this to true for authentication on startup
  requireAuthOnInitialize: true,

  // Pass a vue-router object in to add route hooks with authentication and role checking
  router: router
})
```
````

**important**: make sure to set the mode on your router to 'history' so that it doesn't use hashes!  This will have implications on the serverside.

```
new Router({
  mode: 'history', // Required for Adal library
  ... // Rest of router init
})
```

There are more instructions for use on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-adal), and instructions + a [sample](https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal/tree/master/sample) on [github](https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal)

Comment: Thanks. Note: You should add a disclaimer that you're the author of this addon.

Comment: Done.  Appreciate the tip.

Comment: @Xiaosu with version 1.3.x and up, IE11 is supported.  Let me know if you run into issues / open an issue on github.

Comment: @survirtual thanks for the reply. When I use vue-adal as a depnedency in vue-cli project, it does not work in IE 11. if i just use adal.js, that works fine.

Comment: Is that using the latest version?  1.3.1 was pushed yesterday.

Comment: Thank you for this! @survirtual please continue to work on it!

Comment: Please note that vue-adal is not actively maintained anymore and shouldn't be used for any serious projects. Use ms-adal instead

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure that there is a library to help with security for Vue apps. However, we can easily leverage Adal.js for authentication.

I wrote a simple demo for your reference:

**Index.html**:

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  <script src="node_modules\adal-angular\lib\adal.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
    var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);

    function login() {
      authContext.login();
    }

    function init(configOptions) {
    if (configOptions) {
      // redirect and logout_redirect are set to current location by default
      var existingHash = window.location.hash;
      var pathDefault = window.location.href;
      if (existingHash) {
        pathDefault = pathDefault.replace(existingHash, "");
      }
      configOptions.redirectUri = configOptions.redirectUri || pathDefault;
      configOptions.postLogoutRedirectUri =
      configOptions.postLogoutRedirectUri || pathDefault;

      // create instance with given config
    } else {
      throw new Error("You must set configOptions, when calling init");
    }

    // loginresource is used to set authenticated status
    updateDataFromCache(authContext.config.loginResource);
    }

    var _oauthData = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      userName: "",
      loginError: "",
      profile: ""
    };
    var updateDataFromCache = function(resource) {
      // only cache lookup here to not interrupt with events
      var token = authContext.getCachedToken(resource);
      _oauthData.isAuthenticated = token !== null && token.length > 0;
      var user = authContext.getCachedUser() || { userName: "" };
      _oauthData.userName = user.userName;
      _oauthData.profile = user.profile;
      _oauthData.loginError = authContext.getLoginError();
    };

    function saveTokenFromHash() {
      var hash = window.location.hash;
      var requestInfo = authContext.getRequestInfo(hash);
      if (authContext.isCallback(hash)) {
        // callback can come from login or iframe request

        var requestInfo = authContext.getRequestInfo(hash);
        authContext.saveTokenFromHash(requestInfo);
        window.location.hash = "";

        if (requestInfo.requestType !== authContext.REQUEST_TYPE.LOGIN) {
          authContext.callback = window.parent.AuthenticationContext().callback;
        }
      }
    }

    function isAuthenticate() {
      return _oauthData.isAuthenticated;
    }

    saveTokenFromHash();

    init(config);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="app">
  <p v-if="_oauthData.isAuthenticated">Hello {{ oauthData.userName }}</p>
  <button onclick="login()" v-else>Login</button>
</div>

<script>
  var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      oauthData: _oauthData
    }
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**config.js**:

```
var config = {
  tenant: 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com',
  clientId: '',
  redirectUri: '',
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your time doing this. I'll get back to you once I get it tried.

Comment: Yes, but you'll have to look at adal-vanilla. This answer isn't right though, since adal already does most of this for you.

Comment: @Coreus The code sample above works well for me. The most of other libraries just wrap adal.js to make it fit for the framework like `adal-vanilla`

Comment: With adal 1.0.14 much of the above is not needed as it's handled elsewhere. For example: authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash) I ended up using something in this fashion: https://gist.github.com/psignoret/50e88652ae5cb6cc157c09857e3ba87f

Comment: I also used the `1.0.14` version AdalJS. The code above is not prefect solution, it just help developers to get started to protect the VueJS app with Azure AD. If you already have a solution, you may post and mark it as a answer so that other communities who have the same issue could easily recognize the answer.

Comment: Hi, could you please post your solution as an answer in here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use Adal JavaScript. However, I suggest you to research more on security side for this solution, it doesn't seem to be in line with the new security recommendation, which is to use a PKCE (see https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/). I couldn't find any adal JavaScript documentation for that.

Comment: That's up to the auth authority. If they're using 2FA you're more in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

This was a hard one for me so I'm posting here - hopfully this will save some time to someone:

My problem was that I need not only to authenticate my vue.js app with azure-ad, but I need also to get the security groups to which the user is belonging to.

To achive this, this is what I done:

I used the vue-adal sample app mentioned above (you can find it in: https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal) - under sample folder.

But I still had to make some changes to make it behave the way I need. The problem was that after logging in with my user the sample app used windows.net graph API for retrieving user info with the token from the user authentication, so I had to change in `main.js` this:

```
const graphApiBase = `https://graph.windows.net`
const graphApiResource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

to this:

```
const graphApiBase = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`
const graphApiResource = '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

In addition, inside the return url component I had to change the axios query to get the security groups to which the user belongs to ... so I changed this (in the home.vue file):

```
async getUserInfo () {
    let res = await this.$graphApi.get(`me`, {
        params: {
            'api-version': 1.6
    }
})
```

to this:

```
async getUserInfo () {
    let res = await this.$graphApi.post(`/me/getMemberGroups`, {
        securityEnabledOnly: true
    })
    console.log(res)
    return res.data
}
```

And then the data that I received back from the API contained the security groups to which the user belongs to ...

Comment: Please note that vue-adal is not actively maintained anymore and shouldn't be used for any serious projects. Use ms-adal instead.

Comment: @Coreus Did you mean `ms-asal`? I can't find an `ms-adal` library.

Comment: They've renamed and such. MS is moving away from MS-Adal and now recommends using MS-MSAL instead. You can find that here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal/v/1.3.0-beta.0