# How to Login and Authenticate Microsoft Graph B2C User across ASP Net Core2, VueJS, Xamarin.Forms and Azure Functions C# precompiled (v1 and v2)?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-functions

I am developing a portal, and have this scenario:

1. The user enters the ASP.Net Core 2 Razor Pages Web portal, signup or sign-in with Facebook
2. On the main page, index.cshtml, there is HTML and a simple VueJS with a property {{ Account.Total }}
3. The VueJS brings this Account.Total value from an Azure Function using Axios Javascript library. https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/GetAccountTotal?AccountId=ABC
4. User also logs in UWP and Mobile Xamarin.Forms App
5. The Mobile App, made in Xamarin.Forms also calls this Azure Function to get the Account.Total
6. The UWP App also calls this Azure Function to get the Account.Total

The idea is that the ASP.Net Core would be just a Client, like the UWP, and Xamarin App. The Azure Functions would be the backend, like the Web API; The Microsoft Graph Facebook Authentication would secure all this and identify the User.

The Azure Function need to use the same Graph/Azure AD B2C Authentication. The user will login just one time at the ASP.Net Razor Page, and all related services and calls must read these credentials.

How to configure, and what code is needed to do this Login and Authenticate ***Microsoft Graph B2C*** Facebook User Account across ASP Net Core2, VueJS and Azure Functions C# precompiled (v1 and v2)?

Comment: You need to be more specific: your ASP.Net Core 2 is it MVC or web API ? do you have a VueJs App or it is just a component ? do your azure function need azure ad authentication ? I think there are multiple questions here

Comment: ASP.Net Core 2 Razor Pages, then on Index.cshtml there is a VueJS simple component. Yes, the Azure Function need to use the same Graph/Azure AD B2C Authentication. The user will login just one time, and all related services must read these credentials.

Comment: Why do you need an ASP.Net Core app + an Azure Function. Also if you dont have a client app, you can just authenticate your user through the .Net core app and the .net core communicate with the function (server to server) ?

Comment: The idea is that the ASP.Net Core would be just a Client, like the UWP, and Xamarin App. The Azure Functions would be the WebAPI. The Microsoft Graph Facebook Authentication would secure all this and identify the User.

Comment: I think you should ask a question per problem.

Comment: Here is a link to authenticate to azure ad using vuejs https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437634/how-do-you-authenticate-a-vuejs-app-with-azure-ad/47256428#47256428

Comment: Same for aspnet.core https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

Comment: Same for azure functions https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/hmahrt/2017/03/07/azure-active-directory-b2c-and-azure-functions/

Comment: Grant front-end app access to back end
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-auth-aad#grant-front-end-app-access-to-back-end

Comment: For Facebook we get an access token, and we need to make an HTTP POST to <functionapp>/.auth/login/facebook with the application/json body { 'access_token' : <accesstoken> }
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stuartleeks/2018/02/19/azure-functions-and-app-service-authentication/

Comment: Azure Active Directory B2C: Provide sign-up and sign-in to consumers with Facebook accounts

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-fb-app

Comment: Configure the AD Reply URLs (example: https://contoso.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback )

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-active-directory-authentication#a-nameregister-aregister-your-app-service-app-with-azure-active-directory

Comment: Did you start working on your solution?

Comment: Yes, I am working on it right now, and am having another issues as well. I plan to answer my question when I find the Way to make all work. Please follow me on Twitter, I will follow back https://twitter.com/tonyvca

Comment: Maybe you should ask multiple question, one question for eahc problem ?? It is more an architecture design problem ?

Answer (score 0):

All this look obvious, but after some days trying, I will post here the steps.
(WIll edit this answer to put more details)

But the most important difficult to find part (in order) are:

1) It worked after I added the additionalLoginParams

```
"additionalLoginParams": ["response_type=code id_token", "resource=<app_id>"]
```

on https://resources.azure.com/

At the top of the page, select Read/Write.
In the left browser, navigate to subscriptions >  resourceGroups >  > providers > Microsoft.Web > sites >  > config > authsettings.

Click Edit.

Modify the following property. Replace  with the Azure Active Directory application ID of the service you want to access.

2) On ASP.Net Core 2 you put Login and Logout:

```
<a href="~/.auth/login/aad?post_login_redirect_url=/Index">LOGIN</a><br />
<a href="~/.auth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=/Bye">LOGOUT</a><br />
```

and you can request

```
string UserName = (string)Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME"];
string UserId = (string)Request.Headers["X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID"]; 
string Token = Request.Headers["X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN"];
```

3) Then on the JavaScript, you must Call the Azure Function sending the Authorization Header Bearer Token

```
function WhoAmI() {
    var Token = "@ViewData["Token"]";
    var url = "https://MyFUNCTION.azurewebsites.net/api/WhoAmI";
    var headers = { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${Token}` } };

    //if (Token == "") headers = null;

    axios.get(url,
        headers
    ).then(response => {
        console.log("WhoAmI()");
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
```

Sources:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-how-to#refresh-access-tokens

Maybe I will also need to use
0) ADAL.NET (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory)