# how do i authenticate my vuejs app using azure active directory and get the security groups to which the user belong to

Tags: vue.js, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

i saw something similar here: [How do you authenticate a VueJS app with Azure AD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437634/how-do-you-authenticate-a-vuejs-app-with-azure-ad)

but it did not work for me...

my problem is that after authenticating the user at login - i still needed to get the users security groups and that information was not received using the graph-api described in the above mentioned post

thank you for any help

Answer (score 4):

it was something that took me a long time to figure out so im posting my findings here, hopfully this will help someone:

this was a hard one for me so im posting here - hopfully this will save some time to someone:

my problem was that i need not only to authenticate my vuejs app with azure-ad, but i need also to get the security groups to which the user is belonging to.

to achive this, this is what i done:

i used the vue-adal sample app mentioned above( you can find it in: https://github.com/survirtual/vue-adal ) - under sample folder.

but i still had to make some changes to make it behave the way i need. the problam was that after logging in with my user the sample app used windows.net graph api for retrieving user info with the token from the user authentication, so i had to change in main.js this:

```
const graphApiBase = `https://graph.windows.net`
const graphApiResource = '00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

to this:

```
const graphApiBase = `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0`
const graphApiResource = '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000'
```

in addition, inside the return url component i had to change the axios query to get the security groups to which the user belongs to..so i changed this (in the home.vue file):

```
async getUserInfo () {
      let res = await this.$graphApi.get(`me`, {
        params: {
          'api-version': 1.6
        }
      })
```

to this:

```
async getUserInfo () {
      let res = await this.$graphApi.post(`/me/getMemberGroups`, {
        securityEnabledOnly: true
      })
      console.log(res)
      return res.data
    }
```

and then the data that i received back from the api contained the security groups to which the user belongs to...

Comment: here are some usfull documentation links that can really help construct other queries to this graph-api: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http | https://www.tatvasoft.co.uk/blog/microsoft-graph-and-azure-active-directory-graph-api/ | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters -- hopfully this information save you some time

Comment: also: dont forget to grant permissions to the app to get the data you want in the azure web interface...otherwise you will get 403 in response from the api which is unauthorized